# Wordpress custom plugin page get_header() not rendering menu css

Tags: wordpress, plugins

In my custom plugin page I have included wp-load.php also call function get_header().
It only render the menu but not the css for it, this issue is same for get_footer().

Comment: you have created custom shortcode from custom plugin? or is there any template you have created?

Comment: I have created shortcode for search form. and when user search it will render search page from my plugin.